# How to break the loops properly here to get exact loop gains?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, feedback, loop-gain

I got the circuit with two feedback loops from [this page](http://fox.ece.ufl.edu/Multiple-Loop_Feedback.html).
I'm trying to calculate the exact loop gain of each loop. However, I'm not sure how to break the loop properly so you can account for loading effect, forward transmission and get the exact loop gains without any approximation.
How can I break the loops here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: MiddleBrook comes to mind. See [this EDN article](https://www.edn.com/loop-gain-measurements/) for an example. If you feel it applies, you'll need to decide how. Also see [this picture of an example of how to do this in Spice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igOtz.png).

Comment: @jonk I haven't read the one you linked but from the page I mentioned above it says that the Middlebrook method doesn't account for forward transmission so it is not the exact result.

Comment: I've not encountered a situation where I didn't get useful results from its application. You may be right about the reference saying it won't work. But I never take anything at face and investigating your reference would require me to criticize a web page's writing. And I'm not prepared to do that, today. (It's hard to argue with a web page -- they don't argue back.) If you want to believe what it says, and you may be right about it -- not saying otherwise, then that's fine. If I become sufficiently motivated, I might go see what the argument is about and see if I agree with it. Not today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break the loops at the red crosses as Rob Fox explains it in his
article.
You can do hand analysis or use Tian's method or Middlebrook's GFT.

Middlebrook shows what is an ideal injection point and why it is
normally not enough to inject a single voltage or current.
See https://web.archive.org/web/20160401041428/http://ardem.com/D_OA_Rules&Tools/index.asp .
And there especially chapter 11 and chapter 13.

On the other hand the term loop gain is not well defined.
See https://sites.google.com/site/frankwiedmann/loopgain for a discussion.

By the way there is an interesting discussion between
Prof. Middlebrook and Frank Wiedmann

https://web.archive.org/web/20121025134649/http://groups.yahoo.com/group/Design-Oriented_Analysis_D-OA/message/40

In another thread [How to get exact loop gain expression for this circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/568375/how-to-get-exact-loop-gain-expression-for-this-circuit)
was a question about the return ratio in multiloop feedback.
I answer it here with the example circuit of Rob Fox
as an alternative method.

Now the calculation of Bode's return ratio.
For the theory see the article of Rob Fox and his references to Bode and Mason.

T is the return ratio.
F is the return difference
with F = (1+T) or T=(F-1).

The network determinant of the circuit is:

$$D = \frac{(1 + (G1* G2* R1* R3) + (G1* G2* R1* R4) + (G1* G2* R2* R4) - (G1* R2) + (G2* R1) + (G2* R2) + (G2* R3))}{R1*R2*R3*R4}$$

Partial determinants:

First loop broken. D with G1=0

$$D1 = \frac{1 + G2*R3+G2*R2+G2*R1}{R1*R2*R3*R4}$$

Second loop broken. D with G2=0

$$D2 = \frac{1 - G1*R2}{R1*R2*R3*R4}$$

All loops broken. D with G1=G2=0

$$D12 = \frac{1}{R1*R2*R3*R4}$$

Return differences and ratios:

$$Fx$$ means return diff for component x.

$$Fx_y$$ means return diff for component x with y already broken/inactive.

The key idea is that the return difference is calculated with the partial determinants.

$$F1   =  \frac{D}{D1}$$

$$F2_1 = \frac{D1}{D12}$$

$$F2   =  \frac{D}{D2}$$

$$F1_2 = \frac{D2}{D12}$$

$$F = F1 * F2_1 = \frac{D}{D1} * \frac{D1}{D12} = \frac{D}{D12}$$

$$F = F2 * F1_2 = \frac{D}{D2} * \frac{D2}{D12} = \frac{D}{D12}$$

With the numbers of the example this results in

$$T1   = F1 - 1   = 24.628$$

$$T2_1 = F2_1 - 1 = 120$$

$$T2   = F2 - 1   = -164.21$$

$$T1_2 = F1_2 - 1 = -20$$

$$T = F - 1 = 3100$$

Some notes:

This is pure algebraic.
It is not often used in practice, I think.

To get the network determinant, one has to solve the circuit symbolically (?).

It is not always clear how to interpret the results and use it in the design of a circuit.

The typical loop gain is used, because it can be measured in a circuit.

EDIT: Add denominator to network determinant. Layout of the formulas.

Comment: nice! I see that you got the same result as the page I linked. 
The web archive links don't work for me. 
Is the network determinant the determinant of the admittance matrix with one node grouned? 
I made admittance matrix and calculated but got a different result.  I send it below. 
Also is the `T` the typical loop gain you are refering to? 
https://ibb.co/r5dLDwV

Comment: Would it be 4 loops instead?
https://ibb.co/mNkWsQg

Comment: Your admittance matrix is correct. Mine is without the R1*R2*R3*R4 denominator, which
cancels out in the calculation of F anyway.
I used the transfer function method for the determinant. But need now some checks/proof.
T is here the return ratio. The mentioned typical loop gain method is with opening
the loop for analysis, simulation and measurement. 
Not sure what you mean with 4 loops exactly. Looks like Kirchhoff meshes.
Bodes return ration works with active components. Sure there is a connection
between return ratio, feedback loops and Kirchhoff meshes (?).

Comment: By the way. If you substitute the low pass filter function into Gm1 and Gm2 you 
get the plots of the Fox article.

Comment: I wondered what is the exact definition of a loop in this context for stability analysis.  Is it possible to simply consider a mesh in any electronic circuit and say that it is a feedback loop? In the image I sent, I draw 4 loops and all of them include the active device.

Comment: When you have n loops, you can define n different loop gains with n different phase margins. However, there will be one loop which is most critical (lowest phase margin). This is the loop with the largest time constant - in most cases, the outer "overall" loop. The inner (local) loop have smaller reaction times (for a good design).

Answer (score 1):

In the given circuit I can identify two local loops and one overall loop. Now the question arises for which purpose you want to know the loop gains. In most cases, it is the phase margin of the most critical loop which one is interested in, right?

Obviously, this is the outer overall loop. Hence, you should open this loop at the non-inverting input of the first (most left) opamp and perform the loop gain analysis.

In this case, it is not necessary to apply Middlebrooks double injection method. The result would be very small if compared with the most simple method of voltage injection only (nearly no loading effect)